# Call to a member function get() on a non-object - Symfony and Silex

Tags: php, apache, symfony, composer-php, silex

I just got added to a team working on a project based on Symphony and Silex as PHP frameworks and composer as a package manager. The system is currently being used in production and works just fine.

So what's the problem? The app fails miserably when I run locally:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /Library/WebServer/wsmcrm/session.php on line 9
```

What did I do?

- Reset my apache httpd.conf to the original.
- Edited the httpd.conf to enable php and some other minor tweaks.
- Cloned the repo (master)
- Ran the scripts to have composer install all the libraries in our composer.json file (the /vendor folder now seems to have all the libraries I need),
- Changed DocumentRoot to /Library/WebServer/wsmcrm/
- Created a local copy of our PROD database.
- Updated database connections in our code to point to my local DB for testing.
- Started the apache server
- Started the mysql server

When I visit localhost/ the application fails immediately with the exception above. This is rather rare as the problem is on this line:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use OMG\User;

$session = $app['controllers_factory'];
/*This is line 9 */ $session->get('/', function(Silex\Application $app) {
```

Which tells me that $session is null, which means that 'controllers_factory' is not an array item in $app, which is also very weird since like I said, it works in prod with really no other changes.

Essentially, we call session.php from index.php here:

```
return new RedirectResponse('/session/login');
```

whenever there is no auth cookie stored locally, and /session matches this:

```
$app->mount('/session', include 'session.php');
```

I'm just not really sure what the problem maybe, but I'm sure it's got something to do with my local environment setup.

Any ideas?

Here's the full [httpd.conf](http://pastebin.com/nj3GSxbt) in case you want to look around.

Comment: This is rather bizarre as *controllers_factory* is a [valid key](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.2/src/Silex/Application.php#L76) entry in *$app*. Can you check if *$app* is a valid *Silex/Application* instance? (it should as you said it's a working code, but never hurt to double check :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, it was a problem with my local configuration.

The initial request URI was "/" and that triggered apache to serve index.php. However, when index did a redirect to "/session/*", apache was serving "session.php" directly - hence why "$app" was null, instead of serving index.php and letting him mount "session.php" through the framework.

I had to edit my .htaccess and add:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

so that all requests were passed through index.php for processing, rather than serving the controller directly.

That fixed the issue on my end.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue of session creation. If you are using database session management, make sure you have the proper schema created.

If you use file session, make sure that the session folder that is set in `php.ini` at `session.save_path` is writable from apache user.

But just to be sure, check apache error log too.